# How many is a "large" data set?

Tags: database, large-data-volumes

Assumed infinite storage where size/volume/physics (metrics,gigabytes/terrabytes) won't matter only the number of elements and their labels, statistically pattern should emerge already at 30 subsets, but can you agree that less than 1000 subsets is too little to test, and at least 10000 distinct subsets / "elements", "entries" / entities is "a large data set". Or larger? 
Thanks

Comment: You should specify what kind of data contains your data set and what statistical analysis you want to do with them.

Comment: As @akappa says, without context, it is impossible to say.

Comment: With infinite storage, no data set is "large" :-)

Comment: @marc_s, Processing and fetching would make the "large" dataset "slow."

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you are attempting to ask about how many elements of data set you need to sample in order to ensure a certain degree of accuracy (30 is a magic number from the Central Limit Theorem that comes in to play frequently).

If that is the case, the sample size you need depends on the confidence level and confidence interval.  If you want a 95% confidence level and a 5% confidence interval (i.e. you want to be 95% confident that the proportion you determine from your sample is within 5% of the proportion in the full data set), you end up needing a sample size of no more than 385 elements.  The greater the confidence level and the smaller the confidence interval that you want to generate, the larger the sample size you need.

Here is a nice discussion on the [mathematics of determining sample size](http://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/PD006)
and a handy [sample size calculator](http://www.surveysystem.com/sscalc.htm) if you just want to run the numbers.